# Rotating bone scales/shrinks mesh

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

After I rigged my 1911 gun I rotated the hammers bone to see it shrinks/scales on rotation:
[image: Video]

As you can see the bone has all of its weight on the hammers vertex group, so I dont think weight is the problem.
[image: Video]

Ive seen other threads with similar issues and the answer has always been to apply transforms which I have already done. Im very new to rigging/blender in general so I probably did something stupid.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: how is it rigged? Is the armature modifier and weight painting required for export, otherwise hammer could for instance copy bone loc and rot, or be a child of the bone. My guess is

Comment: Yeah it’s necessary for exporting as I use the bone in unreal engine for some positioning stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently since the root bone had the whole object assigned to it (which obviously includes the hammer) that was causing the distortion. So I simply removed the hammer from the root bones weight paint.